# Yii createCommand update part of string of multiple records

Tags: php, yii, sqlite

I'm using createCommand to replace part of a string in a field of multiple records.
The following code works well:

`Yii::app()->db->createCommand("UPDATE table SET field=replace(field,'" . $old_string . "','" . $model->value . "') WHERE field LIKE '%" . $old_string . "%'")->execute();`

(Yii 1.1)

but, how can I parameterize it so that I can use :oldString & :newString, instead of linking the variables to the query directly?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could use binding param

```
$query = "UPDATE table 
          SET field=replace(field, :old_string , :new_string) 
          WHERE field LIKE concat('%', :old_string2, '%')";

$command = Yii::app()->db->createCommand($query);
$command->bindParam(":old_string", $old_string, PDO::PARAM_STR);     
$command->bindParam(":new_string", $model->value, PDO::PARAM_STR);     
$command->bindParam(":old_string2", $old_string, PDO::PARAM_STR);     
$command->execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to replace values with parameters placeholders in query and pass real values to `execute()`. The only tricky part is parameter for `LIKE`, since `%` needs to be inside of parameter value, not query:

```
$sql = <<<'SQL'
    UPDATE table 
    SET field = replace(field, :old_string, :value) 
    WHERE field LIKE :searchable_old_string
SQL;

Yii::app()->db->createCommand($sql)->execute([
    'old_string' => $old_string,
    'value' => $model->value,
    'searchable_old_string' => "%$old_string%",
]);
```